# not coded symbol

Tags: symbols

Could anyone please help with one right solution?
Convert to english with certain spaces between every letter and words.
l did:

```
eng_dict = {'.-':    'a', '-...':  'b', '-.-.':  'c',
         '-..':   'd', '.':     'e', '..-.':  'f',
         '--.':   'g', '....':  'h', '..':    'i',
         '.---':  'j', '-.-':   'k', '.-..':  'l',
         '--':    'm', '-.':    'n', '---':   'o',
         '.--.':  'p', '--.-':  'q', '.-.':   'r',
         '...':   's', '-':     't', '..-':   'u',
         '...-':  'v', '.--':   'w', '-..-':  'x',
         '-.--':  'y', '--..':  'z', '-----': '0',
         '.----': '1', '..---': '2', '...--': '3',
         '....-': '4', '.....': '5', '-....': '6',
         '--...': '7', '---..': '8', '----.': '9'
        }

nomorse = input("Enter your code here: ")
nomorse_list = nomorse.split(' ')
text = ''
morse= True
for letter in nomorse_list:
    for key in morse_eng_dict.keys():
        if letter == key:
            text = text + str(morse_eng_dict[key])
    if letter == '':
        text = text + " "
if morse == True:
    string = "".join(text)
    print(string)
```

the problem.. Sometimes there can be not possible conversion of some coded symbols. that symbols can be displayed like " * "

for example: "- .... .. .......  - . .- --"   should be "thi*  team"

if try to put like

```
   if letter != key:
                letter = '*'
            text = text + str(morse_eng_dict[key] + '*')
```

that shows * after every doubled letter
the rest of my attempts all resulted text with spaces in every certain letters.

Comment: Here's a small hint for asking questions that make them easier to answer. Instead of `nomorse = input("Enter your Morse code here:")` use `nomorse = "some explicit text that causes your problem"`. Otherwise we need to guess at what you are inputing.

Comment: that is everything clear exactly about you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of notes on the code above. When trying to access the value of a dictionary instead of this...

```py
for key in morse_eng_dict.keys():
    if letter == key:
        text = text + str(morse_eng_dict[key])
```

try

```py
if letter in morse_eng_dict:
    text = text + str(morse_eng_dict[letter])
```

This will accomplish the same thing in a much more efficient way.

If you want to only replace dots and dashes, you have a few options. One would be this...

```py
if letter in morse_eng_dict:
    text += str(morse_eng_dict[letter])
else:
    text += letter
```

Alternatively, you can use [regular expressions](https://regexone.com/) to match values and substitute them. In this case `r'[\.-]*'` can be used to match words morse code words.

Here is a runnable example!

```js
#!/usr/bin/env python
import re

morse_eng_dict = {'.-':    'a', '-...':  'b', '-.-.':  'c',
         '-..':   'd', '.':     'e', '..-.':  'f',
         '--.':   'g', '....':  'h', '..':    'i',
         '.---':  'j', '-.-':   'k', '.-..':  'l',
         '--':    'm', '-.':    'n', '---':   'o',
         '.--.':  'p', '--.-':  'q', '.-.':   'r',
         '...':   's', '-':     't', '..-':   'u',
         '...-':  'v', '.--':   'w', '-..-':  'x',
         '-.--':  'y', '--..':  'z', '-----': '0',
         '.----': '1', '..---': '2', '...--': '3',
         '....-': '4', '.....': '5', '-....': '6',
         '--...': '7', '---..': '8', '----.': '9'
        }

nomorse = input("Enter your Morse code here:")

def replacer(match: re.Match):
    m = match.group()
    return morse_eng_dict.get(m, m)

text = re.sub(r'[\.-]*', replacer, nomorse)
morse = text != nomorse
if morse:
    string = "".join(text)
    print(string)
```

```html
<script src="https://modularizer.github.io/pyprez/pyprez.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specifically check if a given key is present in the dictionary; you don't have to loop through all possible keys.

```
if letter in morse_eng_dict:
    # letter is in the dict.  handle appropriately
else:
    # letter is not in the dict.  handle appropriately
```